# Spring Security OAuth type-safe SpEL builder

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

We are implementing an OAuth2 resource server with spring-security + spring-security-oauth.

The use case is pretty simple :

- A. Some resources are only available for authorized clients
- B. Some resources are only available for (HTTP basic) authenticated users
- C. All other resources are only available for (HTTP basic) authenticated users

With Java Configuration, to enforce security constraints, we use a lot of SpEL like this :

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()

             // A. Only authorized clients
             .antMatchers("/type-a").access("#oauth2.hasScope('READ_SOMETHING')")

             // B. Both authorized clients and users
             .antMatchers("/type-b").access("#oauth2.hasScope('READ_SOMETHING_ELSE') or (!#oauth2.isOAuth() and hasRole('ROLE_USER'))")

             // ... (different flavors of B.) ...

             // C. Everything else is for authenticated users
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and().httpBasic();
}
```

Although this works fine, I don't like :

1. The SpEL markup itself can get tricky and cannot be verified until runtime
2. Repeating constants (scopes, roles) in multiple SpEL strings...
3. Or to prevent duplicated constants, 150-character-long concatenations have poor readability

In general with spring-security, the `HttpSecurity` builder provided by security configuration base classes (`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`) is perfect for simple constraints, but composite/sophisticated constraints end up in SpEL.

With spring-security-oauth2 I don't know any other way than SpEL.

**Question :** Is there any existing utility class that provides some kind of type-safe fluent builder for OAuth2 SpEL ?

Something like :

```
TypicalPerfectlyNamedSpringFrameworkDreamClass.builder()
    .startExpressionGroup()
        .hasOAuth2Scope("MY-SCOPE")
    .endExpressionGroup()
    .or()
    .startExpressionGroup()
        .isNotOAuth2Request()
        .and()
        .hasRole("ROLE_USER")
    .endExpressionGroup()
    .toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: "no, there is no such utility".

Comment: thanks, probably too much dancing around in that question anyway